# instagram implementation for pulling followers list

Tags: android, instagram

I want to implement an Instagram app in android that will list all the followers of the Instagram account which the user is currently logged-in to. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: have you found anything?

Answer (score 0):

(hope it will help full to some one who is going to go through this question)
hello
I have managed to get the result 
first clue got for below link
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/
in this link you can see the json link need to get used
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

using json parsing you will get the result